# QT how to draw map from pixel and create tooltip

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw map

For example map size `1000x1000` but it is possible that may be larger.
But i dont want to make window size more than `600x600`.

I want to put "pixel" size 2x2 (to be more visible) (pixel can have one of 3 colours, but i call it pixel bcoz it is small )

But when i draw pixel with specific colour, and when i put mouse over this pixel i want to show tooltip near arrow (i.e mouse arrow) With some information, but all pixels have own tooltip (other informations)

Questions:

1. How to make that i draw map larger than window, and can move it with mouse (grab -> move -> drop) and with scroll bars.
2. How to make tooltip ? And how to put pixel on this map ?
3. How to catch event, when i click on pixel ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to make that i draw map larger than window, and can move it with
>   with scroll bars.

A [QScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) is probably the widget you want to use for that.  See Qt's included "plugandpaint" or "imageviewer" example programs for how it can be done.

> and with mouse (grab -> move -> drop).

If you want the user to be able to scroll the visible portion of the image by clicking and dragging on the background, you can do that by overriding the [mousePressEvent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent), [mouseMoveEvent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent), and [mouseReleaseEvent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent) methods of your widget that displays the map image.  Note that using a left-mouse-click to scroll the map may conflict with your goal of using left-mouse-click to draw pixels on the map, though.

> How to make tooltip ?

You can make a tooltip appear by calling the static method [QToolTip::showText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#showText)

> And how to put pixel on this map ?

Override your widget's paintEvent() to call [drawPoint()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawPoint-2) or [drawPoints()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawPoints-2) after it redraws the image.  (Or alternatively, you could convert the [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) containing your map image into a [QBitmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbitmap.html), write the updated pixels in to the QBitmap, then convert the QBitmap back to a QPixmap again; that might be more efficient in certain cases)

> How to catch event, when i click on pixel ?

Override mousePressEvent() on your widget that displays the map.

Comment: I dont want to use left-click mouse to draw pixels (program do it), drawPoints have event 'onMouseOver' (then i have to know which data i have to show, and when )

Comment: mouseMoveEvent() is similar to 'onMouseOver'.  Note that if you want mouseMoveEvent() to be called even no mouse buttons are being held down, you will need to call setMouseTracking(true) on your widget.  As for drawing the pixels, just add the call(s) to painter->drawPixels() into your widget's paintEvent() method -- note that you'll need to draw all of the added pixels on every call, since paintEvent() redraws the entire widget.

Comment: Frienser could you told me about zoom image? (for example with mouse scrolls) when i zoom image with this pixels, then how can i know on what Pixel mouse indicate? (maybe it is possible to assign to pixel some data for example, text with data to show OR own identificator to identify pixels)

Comment: If by zoom you mean pan, the QScrollArea object will take care of adding in the proper offsets.  If by zoom you mean shrink/magnify, QScrollArea won't handle that; you might use a QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView instead (then you could implement a magnify transformation via QGraphicsView::transform() or QGraphicsView::setMatrix).  Alternatively you could pass in the necessary parameters to QPainter::drawImage() to scale the image up or down as part of drawing it inside paintEvent(), but that's a little trickier to get right.

Comment: Frienser tell me - `scene->addEllipse(2, 2, 3, 3, pen);` and how to add tooltip with text "First Eclipse" on this eclipse ?

Comment: addEllipse returns a pointer to the QGraphicsEllipseItem that was added.  Call setToolTip() on that object.